# Не получается добавить openssl в проект qt на Ubuntu

Tags: linux, qt, библиотеки, openssl

Не могу добавить openssl в рофайл qt, не нашел в интернете понятной информации о том, что указывать в pro вайле. Что нужно добавить в профайл, если библиотека скачена с репозитория и находятся по адресу /usr/src.

в профайле написано

```
INCLUDEPATH += openssl

LIBS += openssl/libcrypto.a -ldl -lpthread
LIBS += openssl/libssl.a
```

Папка с заголовками openssl находится в папке с проектом. QT все равно не видит заголовки